# How can I place a div on top of an embedded video player in chrome

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, vimeo

I have a code for placing a div on top of an iframe, which works.
However, when I am setting the iframe's src to a youtube/vimeo player, in chrome the iframe stays on top (it works fine in safari and FF) .

Is there some way to fix this? 
CSS:

```
#over{
    float: left;
    margin-top: -293px;
    margin-left: 185px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    height: 30px;
}
iframe{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 550px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>
  <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67124108?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ffffff&amp;wmode=transparent">
    You don't have iframe support, unfortunately
  </iframe>
  <div id="over">I'm over the iframe</div>
</div>
```

[ it can be seen in work here : http://jsfiddle.net/QPXAT/ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you tried adding a `z-index`, did you specify positioning? `z-index` only works on positioned elements. so I added `position: relative` to both. Is this the effect you were going for?

http://jsfiddle.net/QPXAT/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to mess with `z-index`.
Remove float and add `position: absolute` to top `<div>` and it should work.

```
#over {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  top: 293px;
}

iframe {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 550px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not an issue with the iframe, its an issue with the flash player.

Flash has the so called `wmode` which specifies how the embedded object should be displayed with other html content.

Usually it is on top of everything, but it can be also specified to honor `z-index` etc.

wmode=window : Usually the default option.  This puts the Flash movie on top of all other content on the HTML page.

wmode=opaque : This mode is supposed to let Flash play well within an HTML page and adhere to z-index  ordering.

Here is a good summary:

http://www.8bitrocket.com/2011/02/11/quick-guide-to-wmode-and-flash-embedding/

Comment: tried adding z-index with wmode=opaque, no good - works in safari and FF, not in Chrome.

Comment: wmode has to be added to the flash object - not the iframe, which you cannot do since it is hosted on youtube.